# Creating front-end (Java) user interactive table using MySQL as back-end

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I'm a student, intrested in Java programming. Now im trying to create user interactive form.

Untill now, I have created a form view, using swing components, JLable, JTextfield where user enters data. JButtons, 'new' 'save' 'delete' 'edit', which listens user action through ActionListner.

A table that 'extends' AbstractTableModel. Table values are the ResultSet values. i have used MySQL connectivity.

Table is displayed. User can now add new row to it, using 'New' and 'Save' button.
Please watch this

[image]

My problem is, i need the corresponding TextFields to display the corresponding row user selects in the displayed table, so that 'edit' and 'delete' would be user interactive. users are allowed to select table's row.
Need Help.

Im sorry if any mistake in my question format and language. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

on row select event, populate the values of text fields with tables selected row values.

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in [*How to Use Tables*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html), `JTable` will supply a default editor for any cell in your `TableModel` that returns true from `isCellEditable()`. Just double click on the cell. See also [*User Selections*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#selection) for more on selection listeners.